# Preg_Match - RegEx Error

Tags: php

With the following code

```
$regex = "^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
    ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
    ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$";

    if(!preg_match($regex,$subemail)){
      $form->setError($field, "* Email invalid");
    }

    $subemail = stripslashes($subemail);
}
```

I am receiving the following error

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even if you would fix your delimiters your pattern would fail on **a lot** of emailaddresses: https://emailtester.pieterhordijk.com/test-pattern/NTE

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 0):

Right now it thinks the `^` is the opening delimiter, and therefore is expecting another one at the end. You can use any number of delimiters, such as `/` and `/`, or `@` and `@`, or `<` and `>`, etc. The one below uses `/` and `/` as its opening/closing delimiters:

```
     $regex = "/^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
         ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
         ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must surround your pattern with `#` or `/` like this : `"#[abc]+#"`

Personnaly I use # because it is more visible than /

For email validation standard PHP function use `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)